# Padding behaving different between browsers

Tags: html, css

I got this project going on and I have a container with a gradient fading from transparent to white fixed at the bottom. My goal is to make the container look like it's fading in as the user scolls.

BUT I have a problem, the content at the bottom of container is sort of hidden by the gradient itself. I decided to add a padding-bottom to the container so the content would 100px far from the bottom (exacly the height of the gradient, 100px)

It worked exactly as I expected on Chrome, but on Firefox and IE the padding is not "taking space".

This is my css relatively to the container

```
.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you still would like a link to the main project so you can see it in action and maybe get a better view of the problem [click here](http://inovlancer.com/projetos/m.cityoffuture.org)

I would really appreciate some help on this. It's the only thing I'm missing to end the project.

EDIT: If I am not being clear enough, please ask questions.

Comment: Add the padding to the element inside the box. Welcome to the wonderful world of the border-box-model.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I'm sorry, you meant that I should create an element inside the container and make it have the 100px?

Comment: It's a container, so add the padding to the bottom of whatever element is inside of it and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Well, I thought about that before and I would do it if the content wasn't so variable. I needed a way to do this "automaticaly" regardless the content inside the container. Do you happen to know any other solution?